# What are the long-term consequences of using "sudo gem update"?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm

So, I've been using the wrong practice of doing:

```
sudo gem update [user-defined-gem-command]
```

when updating all of my gems and Ruby-related stuff.

While I know this works, the makers of RVM and Rubygems really discourage against this. It supposedly has something to do with `sudo gem update` installing all gems to the system version of Ruby.

Could someone explain the consequences of having done this?

I'm currently changing to using RVM to install my Gems and Ruby related updates. Is there a way to undo any damage I've created by using sudo to install? Or is this a minor problem?

Comment: `sudo gem update` has been scientifically proven to cause cavities and dandruff so don't use it. Actually it updated the "system" Ruby. As long as you didn't `gem uninstall ...` any gems you should be OK. Use RVM or rbenv and READ THEIR INSTRUCTIONS to learn how to properly use their features and update gems in their environment. Basically, with those tools you *never* need to use `sudo` for a standard installation again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `sudo` is only an issue if you're using RVM or rbenv. If you're using bog standard Ruby, `sudo` is *required* in most installations because your non-privileged user doesn't own the Ruby installation.

RVM and rbenv are built on the concept of your user compiling and owning its own rubies—if you use sudo in that case, you break the model; root will compile, install, and own Ruby and the gems. (And, depending on your environment, gems may be installed in the system Ruby rather than the one you have defined in rbenv/RVM).

Comment: Using "sudo" to update should be safe. Using it to remove can cause problems on Mac OS, because Apple pre-installs Ruby for their own purposes, and removing gems could cause things to break. Updating them shouldn't break anything.

Comment: I can not agree, `sudo` does not preserve environment variables, it is not safe to use it with any ruby environment manager.

Comment: Never use `sudo` and `gem` together!

Answer (score 0):

you can go and `sudo gem uninstall` all the gems listed in `sudo gem list`.

i don't think that this is necessary. all the possible harmful things would have already appeared during installation (that you are executing with root privileges).

just go on and use rvm, rbenv, chruby or whatever virtual ruby environment manager you want.

Comment: "you can go and sudo gem uninstall all the gems listed in sudo gem list"? Do *NOT* do this if running on Mac OS. Apple installs Ruby for their own purposes, and uninstalling their gems will break their Ruby.

Comment: @theTinMan I don't see any pre-installed gems on OS X

Comment: "nobody ever uses that ruby"? Wrong. Apple installs applications that use that Ruby, and people use those apps.

Comment: Prior to 10.8 previous versions had a good number of pre-installed gems. Apple's stripped them in the current Mac OS. For fun run `locate .rb | grep /Library` and see what shows up; There's a lot of interesting stuff.

Comment: I have RVM and I ran some commands with `sudo` and some without. After that I had a lot of errors trying to run stuff and ended up reinstalling Ruby via rvm *without* `sudo`

Answer (score 0):

There is no demage if you used `sudo gem install` - it's just wasted space, you can use `sudo gem uninstall` to get it back.

For any ruby version manager it might get dangerous when you use `sudo gem` as `sudo` does reset your environment variables*, this effectively disables the ruby environment switcher you tried to use and gets you back to your system ruby.

'* there are rare cases when you can configure your `sudo` to either preserve the environment (bad security practice) or to have some extra environment (complicated maintenance).